# How to ascertain the sim used to make an outgoing call in android programmatically in a dual sim phone?

Tags: android, telephony

I am upto building an android app in which I need to detect the sim through which an outgoing call is placed in an dual sim phone. How do I ascertain if it's sim1 or sim2 through which the call has been placed?